# jquery to loop and assign data from an Asp.net core Razor page foreach

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I am getting data from a table and display it with

```
@{
        int i = 0;
    }

    @foreach (var item in Model.RCACategoryMains)
    {
        <div id="DivRows" class="row no-gutters mb-1">
            <div class="col-md-1">
                <span class="form-control">@Model.RCACategoryMains[i].IdRCAM</span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <span id="mainData[@i]" onclick="alert(this.id)" class="form-control" >@Model.RCACategoryMains[i].Category"</span>
                <input id="inputData[@i]" type="text" class="form-control bg-white" name="selectedCategory" asp-for="RCACategoryList[i].RCACatName" name="selectedCategory[@i]" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 text-center">
                <input id="selectData[@i]" type="checkbox" name="checkBox[@i]" data-toggle="toggle" data-on="Yes" data-off="No" data-width="200" data-height="40" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger">
            </div>
        </div>
        i++;
    }
```

and if the user tick the checkbox, data from mainData to be written into inputData with jquery. I can only do one field but not loop

```
$(function () {
        $("#DivRows").on("change", function () {
            var dataGet = @Model.RCACategoryMains;

            var data = $("#mainData").text();
            if ($("#selectData").prop("checked") == true) {
                $("#inputData").val(data)
            }
            else {
                $("#inputData").val("")
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer with the help of one friend

```
$(function () {
        $("#DivRows").on("change", function () {
            $("[id^='selectData']").on("change", function () {
                var n = $(this).attr('id').split('_').pop();
                var data = $("#mainData_" + n).text();
                if ($("#selectData_" + n).prop("checked") == true) {
                    $("#inputData_" + n).val(data)
                }
                else {
                    $("#inputData_" + n).val("")
                }
            })
        });
    });
```